# Select Subset of Columns based on Vector R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 300 columns of data.
I created a vector with 126 elements that are the column names of 126 of the 300.
I want to subset the 300 based on not being in my 126. They are NOT in order, so I can't simply remove by specifying -1:-126.

I tried various things with grep and matrix operations, but they did not work. Such as the following which did not work. x has 300 columns. f contains vector of 126 column names I want to exclude from x1.

```
x1 <- x[, -which(names(x), %in% f)]
```

If I definitively use a variable name or several, I can get it to work, but I don't want to type out the 126 elements in f.

Comment: For further clarification, I want to be able to use the elements in f as if I had specified f=c(element1of_f, element2of_f, ... , element126of_f)

Comment: `x[, !names(x) %in% f]`?

Comment: did you use the select from dplyr with the arguments : start_with, end_with, contains ... ?

Comment: x%>% select(-f)  -> x1 should work for your example

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `%in%`:

```
names.use <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% f)]
```

Then `names.use` will contain the names of all the columns which are *not* contained in your vector of names `f`.

To subset your data frame using the columns you want, you can use the following:

```
df.subset <- df[, names.use]
```

Comment: I tried this and it selected the other names, but not the data. It defined a vector with colnames I wanted, but no data.

Comment: Just subset your original data frames using the columns you want.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do:

```
subset(x, select=f)
```

Unlike using %in%, this will throw an error if one of the values in *f* is not a column name in *x*, which can be helpful for spotting typos if you've typed out some of them manually.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a `data.table` solution with a reproducible example.

```
# load library
library(data.table)

# get data
data(iris)

# convert your dataset into data.table
setDT(iris)

# vector of columns you DON'T want
f <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")


# subset
output <- iris[, !f, with = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 6):

A little bit late but this can help others - a clean way of getting this done with `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect) 

df %>% 
  select(all_of(names(f)))
```

Some reproducible examples - 1) Subsetting from the names in a vector:

```
dplyr::starwars

f <- c("name","eye_color","gender")

starwars %>% 
  select(all_of(f))
```

2)Subsetting from the column names of another data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(letters =  c("a","b","c","d"),
                  numbers = 5:8,
                  fruits =  c("apple","grape","lemon","orange"),
                  animals =  c("frog","cat","fish","lizard"))

df2 <- data.frame(letters =  c("l","m","n","o"),
                 numbers = 13:16)

df %>% 
  select(all_of(names(df2)))
```

Check out for `all_of( )` and `any_of( )` functions, from the package `tidyselect`. I'm pretty sure `dplyr` imports them automatically, but I often load that package just in case.

Comment: `dplyr` will load them all. Probably don't need to worry about `tidyselect` package for interactive use. It's more useful for the developer types referencing them in their own packages. So in this example, I would suggest simply loading `dplyr` instead of the entire `tidyverse` and `tidyselect`, but that's me.

Comment: That's good to know @Adam. I load the whole `tidyverse` because I use `readr` to read my data and I often want to make some graphs using `ggplot2`. So, loading `tidyverse` spares me some time. But I agree that in this case loading only `dplyr` would be enough.

Comment: Use `any_of` if you are not sure if the vector contain some legit columns' names

Comment: `df %>% select(any_of(names(f)))`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everyone for answering so quickly. A couple of your solutions worked. I realized the biggest problem I had was that I didn't a true vector f!  And once I did, it was still being treated as a factor!  So I thought I would post what I did with your help to fix it.

```
f <- select(filter(hash_t,(variable %in% c("a",...,"z"))),X) #wasn't a vector...
f[,1]<-sapply(f[,1],as.character) # had to remove factor info from f; still not a vector...
f<-f[,1] # Now I had a vector!
x1<-x[,!names(x) %in% f]  #worked!
```

Many of the thoughts posted worked. I just had a problem with my selection criteria not being a proper vector and having some factor issues associated with it.

Comment: A couple of solutions worked?  There are only two answers other than yours.  In general, when you ask a question you should mark an answer correct.  If none really answer your question then you not mark, but marking makes your question more valuable to others with a similar problem.

Comment: Well, Soto's comment was first and correct and the simplist...but not posted as an answer. Both your revised answer works, as well as Rafael's. The reason I couldn't get such methods to work initially was my incorrect construction of a vector to subset with.  That is why I posted my answer; to help others that might have similar issues. I thought it was a bit ostentatious to mark my own answer as correct....and it won't let me; I just tried :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `all_of` or `any_of` from `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)

starwars %>% 
  select(all_of(c("name", "eye_color", "gender")))

starwars %>% 
  select(any_of(c("name", "eye_color", "gender", "no_column")))
```